# Figuring out when a XMLHttpRequest request was made without callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm trying to overload the XMLHttpRequest.* method in JavaScript so a webpage can figure out if an Ajax request took place without using any intrusive callbacks. Now, something like this works relatively fine when using most JS frameworks:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.getResponseHeader = function() {
 alert('O hai, looks like you made an AJAX request.');
}
```

However, there are two catches:

- getResponseHeader can't be used as *getResponseHeader* anymore.
- It doesn't work in simple AJAX examples. i.e. `xmlhttp.open("GET","simple.html",false);`

Is there any way JS can mirror `XMLHttpRequest.open()` or any way that I can chain something to it. I've tried a million paradigms (factory, cloning, wrapping -- most resulting in infinite recursion) and nothing seems to be working. Maybe it's just impossible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the original in some variable before you override the method and then call that variable within the function you overrode:

```
var temp = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader;
XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader = function() { temp.apply(this, arguments); };
```

That should let you track uses without overriding the functionality provided by the original function.

Comment: the temp as parameter to apply should be `this` to maintain scope of the original call

Comment: It would also be better to create this in a function scope so that the `temp` variable isn't place in the global scope

Comment: Thanks Gaby, I've edited to reflect that. And Anthony: I always try to minimize globals, but as I only needed 2 lines of code to illustrate I didn't want to complicate things

Comment: Almost correct. You still need prototype manipulation: XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() { XMLHttpRequestWrapper.apply(this, arguments); alert('It worked!'); }; -- but thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

XmlHttp is going to be a real problem, its a COM object and doesn't support the sort of prototype manipulation you want to use.  Worse yet JQuery avoids `XmlHttpRequest` in IE even when its available it uses XmlHttp instead.

Comment: About jQuery always using an ActiveX object in IE, even if `XMLHttpRequest` is available: not true, it does only do so if `protocol == "file:"`.