# Log upon AJAX call or URL change

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can I add javascript code that logs every time the user is executing an AJAX call or changing the URL(exiting my page)
I want this piece of code to identify the ajax call automatically, I don't want to do it manually wherever there is an ajax call

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - just asking for the code isn't really what this forum is about. Please post something that you've already tried or at least something that shows us that you've thought about it for more than the time it took to write this question. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to use jQuery than try this one:

create a common function for all ajax requests

```
function ajxCall(url,data,method)
{
  $('#logDiv').html(url+'<br>'); // Placing all request URLs in a debug div
  $.ajax({url : url,
          method : method ,
          data : data ,  // data will be a jason object or you can set it by changing dataType
          dataType:'JSON'})
} 

function someEvent() // assign this handler to your event
{
  ajaxCall('http::localhost/login.php',            
           {username:'my_user',password:my_password,
           'POST'});
}
```

You can also create it with out jQuery. I have just described the idea. Hope It helps :) regards.

Comment: I am looking for something generic that is agnostic to the code that I am using, I am not the on who writes the code, I can just add to it