# JavaScript Ajax LIstener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a listener to receive ajax events before any Ajax method is invoked. 
I see there is an [ajaxLIstsner in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) which would work if all my ajax requests were coming from JQuery. But there are not.  So, question is how would I implement such a listener in core JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of events do you want to listen out for?

Comment: That's impossible without messing with the builtin objects. Why would you need that? Just use some kind of notification system like jQuery does.

Comment: maybe this can be helpful -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event

Comment: If you're just doing this for debugging, it would be far easier to just open your network tab in the console. I can't think of any other reason you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the xhr prototype, see http://oreilly.com/pub/h/4133