# XMLHttpRequest prototype of onreadystatechange not called

Tags: javascript, ajax, uiwebview

I'm trying to detect when any ajax call finishes in my UIWebView. I modified the code in this answer: [JavaScript detect an AJAX event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event) to the best of my abilities. Here is my attempt:

```
var s_ajaxListener = new Object();
s_ajaxListener.tempOnReadyStateChange = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onreadystatechange;
s_ajaxListener.callback = function () {
    window.location='ajaxHandler://' + this.url;
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert("onreadystatechange called");
    s_ajaxListener.tempOnReadyStateChange.apply(this, arguments);
    if(s_ajaxListener.readyState == 4 && s_ajaxListener.status == 200) {
        s_ajaxListener.callback();
    }
}
```

I'm injecting this into the webView but the alert is never firing. If I place an alert at the beginning or end of the script, it'll fire so I'm fairly certain there are no syntax errors.

I'm not a JS guy so I'm hoping this is a trivial problem.

Comment: Try inverting the order of operations: first define `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onreadystatechange`, then assign a reference to `s_ajaxListener.tempOnReadyStateChange`.

Comment: @bfavaretto no beans.

Comment: @bfavaretto maybe I didn't understand completely though, could you post a code example in an answer?

Comment: I'm realizing there may be more to it, I'll do some tests first.

Comment: @Lance did you get this figured out? If so can you share your answer?

Comment: @Bot never got this to work reliably. Ended up solving my problem by injecting a CSS rule into the HTML.

Comment: @Lance I am wanting to know when googles ajax search results are done in my uiwebview. Would your CSS rule help me?

Comment: @Bot I was trying to detect when a banner was added and hide it. I just used CSS to hide the banner no matter when it appeared. Doesn't sound like that is your goal. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a generic `onreadystatechange` in `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` didn't work for me. However the code you linked to can be easily adapted to invoke a custom function whenever that event occurs:

```
var s_ajaxListener = {};
s_ajaxListener.tempOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
s_ajaxListener.tempSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
// callback will be invoked on readystatechange
s_ajaxListener.callback = function () {
    // "this" will be the XHR object
    // it will contain status and readystate
    console.log(this);
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(a,b) {
  if (!a) var a='';
  if (!b) var b='';
  s_ajaxListener.tempOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  s_ajaxListener.method = a;  
  s_ajaxListener.url = b;
  if (a.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
    s_ajaxListener.data = b.split('?');
    s_ajaxListener.data = s_ajaxListener.data[1];
  }
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(a,b) {
  if (!a) var a='';
  if (!b) var b='';
  s_ajaxListener.tempSend.apply(this, arguments);
  if(s_ajaxListener.method.toLowerCase() == 'post')s_ajaxListener.data = a;
  // assigning callback to onreadystatechange
  // instead of calling directly
  this.onreadystatechange = s_ajaxListener.callback;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6xqu/

Comment: Using this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {}); may be cleaner

Comment: Maybe this.attachEvent should have been used as a fallback then, but your answer is still very good :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your feedback. If I were to answer this question today, I'd probably go with just addEventListener.

Comment: Since addEventListener is supported by IE9+, it clearly makes sense :)