# Recreating jQuery's ajaxStart and ajaxComplete functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, hook

I'm trying to reproduce jQuery's functions [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete) and [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart) without jQuery so that they could be used in any environment with no library dependencies (it's a special use case). These functions allow for an event listener to be called before and after any ajax request. In my example, I call them preAjaxListener and postAjaxListener.

I'm trying to accomplish it by hooking into the XMLHttpRequest object and overwriting/decorating `open` and `send`. Yes, I know this is dirty.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (function(orig){
    return function(a,b,c){
        this._HREF = b; // store target url
        return orig.apply(this, arguments); // call original 'open' function
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = (function(orig){
    return function(){
        var xhr = this;
        _core._fireAjaxEvents('pre', xhr._HREF); // preAjaxListener fires

        var rsc = xhr.onreadystatechange || function(){}; // store the original onreadystatechange if it exists
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ // overwrite with custom function
            try {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4){
                    _core._fireAjaxEvents('post', xhr._HREF); // postAjaxListneer should fire
                    this.onreadystatechange = rsc;
                } 
            } catch (e){ }
            return rsc.apply(this, arguments); // call original readystatechange function
        };

        return orig.apply(this, arguments); // call original 'send' function
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

I do not want to write wrapper functions to make ajax requests. I want to be able to hook into any ajax request made by any library (or with vanilla js) on the page.

So far, only the `preAjaxListener` function works. I can't seem to figure out why, but it seems that `onreadystatechange` is never being called. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/QTQ5s/

Comment: Why are you touching the native prototype? Create your own wrapper object.

Comment: Because I can! :)

I know it's dirty, but I do not want to write wrapper functions to make ajax requests. I'm in a situation where there are scripts on the page which I have no control over and I want to be able to hook into any ajax request made by any library (or with vanilla js).

Comment: So you want to capture every XHR request/response on the page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to be able to run a function before it's sent, and after a response comes back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `.onreadystatechange` wasn't working because I was testing with jQuery and jQuery's ajax methods manipulate and removes the `onreadystatechange` property.

However, adding an event listener for `loadend` works just fine everywhere but IE. For IE, I set up an interval instead - not the optimal solution, but it works for my needs. *I only intended this script to work on IE8+ and modern browsers.*

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = (function(orig){
    return function(){
        _core._fireAjaxEvents('pre', this._HREF);

        if (!/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
            this.addEventListener("loadend", function(){
                _core._fireAjaxEvents('post', this._HREF);
            }, false);
        } else {
            var xhr = this,
            waiter = setInterval(function(){
                if(xhr.readyState && xhr.readyState == 4){
                    _core._fireAjaxEvents('post', xhr._HREF);
                    clearInterval(waiter);
                }
            }, 50);
        }

        return orig.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Comment: How can we use it?

Comment: I run this code and after ajax at page I see error in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: _core is not defined`

Comment: at Google Chrome 50

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich You can take a look at my full fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/QTQ5s/ `_core` is just a plain object which I was using as a placeholder in place of a library I was working on.

Comment: @nderscore very nice solution mate!