# Catch every xhr request

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve `$.ajaxSuccess` in javascript. I take some refrence from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689481/recreating-jquerys-ajaxstart-and-ajaxcomplete-functionality) question. The method I am using works fine when I use it every XHR request but I'm in a situation where there are scripts on the page which I have no control over and I want to be able to hook into any ajax request made by any library (or with vanilla js). So how to attached `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.check` to document so that we can catch every XHR request. Here is some working

//Script reference taken from w3schools [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get)

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.check=function(){
this.addEventListener("loadend", function(){
                alert(0);
            }, false);

}
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.check()
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: did you try this example: https://gist.github.com/indiejoseph/3047593 ?

Comment: @shershen It is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689481/recreating-jquerys-ajaxstart-and-ajaxcomplete-functionality. By changing in navtive code is only option ?