# Know when form is submitted

Tags: javascript

I have one main page in which we have a form coming from Iframe. When submit the form browser making a post request so I want execute a function after form is submit successfully. The problem is we cannot use any library like jquery and there is cross domain issue with ajax also. So we have to use `form` element to submit a form.

HTML example

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit"
</form>
```

Post message in console after submit a from

```
 POST http://www.example.com/dir/mmr/call/plaincall/ajaxService.getone.dwr
```

Comment: So we know your assignment. What is the question? Also, remember that jQuery is just a library that runs on JavaScript as well. *Everything* you can do in jQuery you can do with just JavaScript as well.

Comment: so I want execute a function after form is submit.

Comment: Is the form submitted via a submit button?

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek Yes I am using submit button

Comment: *"so I want execute a function after form is submit"* is still not a question. A question would look something like: *"I searched, found this example, tried to implement it like so, and now it doesn't work and I get this error message I don't understand. Can you help me solve this issue?"*. StackOverflow is not RentACoder.

Comment: go here and do whatever you want with it http://jsbin.com/xuqecihule/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onSubmit event handler of the form element like so

```
// This adds an onSubmit event handler that will call myFunction
// when the form is submitted
<form onsubmit='myFunction()'>
    // Your stuff in the form goes here
</form>
```

Now in your javascript you can write

```
function myFunction() {
    // Take action here
}
```

Comment: What about the `onsubmit` event of the form?

Comment: That would definitely be a better solution, will edit.

Comment: I use that but problem is it will execute after validate the form but it will not check the the response whether it submitted successfully or not

Comment: I have also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689481/recreating-jquerys-ajaxstart-and-ajaxcomplete-functionality question but it only working with .send request