# Does .ajaxStart() in jquery works for requests sent by xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my javascript code, I have a function that uses xmlhttpRequest() to send many requests.

Now I want to show a loading spinner in the waiting time when the function is being executed. (assuming this function is time-cost)

So if I use $(document).ajaxStart() to set the triggering of the spinner, will it be OK? My confusion is that, I do not know whether the settings in $(document).ajaxStart() works for ajax calls sent by the built-in XmlHttpRequest.

In otherwords, is the following code supposed to work?

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loading.hide();
  });

var xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

And If I do not want to use jquery, is there good ways to set the spinner?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery why aren't you using it for the Ajax stuff? If you don't, why can't you do the same thing in your JS by checking the readyStates?

Comment: Let's say, I do not want to use ajax, then what;s the trick to show the spinner?

Comment: You... don't want to use Ajax? In any case, assuming you actually meant "I don't want to use jQuery", by using normal DOM manipulation with your `onreadystatechange` handler.

Comment: Let's say, I do not want to use jquery, then what's the trick to display the spinner?  By checking the readystate of xmlhttp==4, I can set the callback. But what I want to display is not the callback, but the spinner. I want it to be displayed when ajax starts, not when responses are received.  Maybe I can check xmlhttp==2 ?  (which has similar effect as .ajaxStart()...

Comment: Looking for the same thing, not sure whats with the down vote or the smart arse comments above, if you aren't going to be helpful and just want to use this forum for this kind of thing, I'd suggest you take it out on someone who actually deserves it.

Comment: Anyone coming across this question should have a look at this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691080/3462483

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, since jQuery calls these functions only by using its `.ajax` methods.

You could use jQuery methods for all your AJAX calls, as they're way easier to use (in my opinion at least).