# Catching tags fired on website [JS]

Tags: javascript, tags, google-chrome-devtools

do you know way, how to catch particular tag fired on the website? I think, i would basically know the way it works in network section in chrome developer tools, but to get to this data by javascript

Comment: What do you mean by `tags fired`? Do you mean analytics tracking?

Comment: yes, exacly, i'd like to access data from network section in dev tools in js

Comment: This question might give you an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event Is this what you want? I don't think you can also grab requests for other assets like images or files.